# User Not receiving temporary password in email

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Users are not receiving temporary passwords in email. 
I'm trying to create user in cognito with lambda function.

```
'use strict'
const AWS= require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log("event is ",event)

    var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({apiVersion: '2016-04-18'});

    var params = {
        UserPoolId: process.env.userpool, 
        Username: event.queryStringParameters.username, 
        DesiredDeliveryMediums: ['EMAIL'],
        ForceAliasCreation: false,
        MessageAction: 'SUPPRESS',
        TemporaryPassword: '******',
        UserAttributes: [
            {
                 Name: 'email_verified',
                 Value: "true"
            },

            {
                Name: 'email',
                Value: event.queryStringParameters.email
            },
            {
                Name: 'name', 
                Value: event.queryStringParameters.name
            }
        ]
    };
    cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminCreateUser(params, function(err, data) {
       if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     console.log(data);           // successful response
         var response = {
                "statusCode": 200,
                "headers": {
                    "User": "Created successful",
                    "x-custom-header" : "my custom header value",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"  
                },
                "body": JSON.stringify(data),
                "isBase64Encoded": false
             };
             callback(null, response);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using `MessageAction: 'SUPPRESS'`. Remove that and the proper email will be sent.